# entered form input data is not showing in confirmation page

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-5

I worked on the stepper form,

user entered the data and clicks the next button and untill confirmarion page,See there changes and submit the form.if user not an logged user the redirect to the loign page.

This I done so far.I do research in google,and accidendly remove the css and checked its works or not then I found the problem.

Its only works fine When I removed bootstrap 5(entred form inputs shows on confirmation page) ,why I dont undersatand logic behind this,can you some one help me?

```
<?php
// Start or resume the session
session_start();

// Check if the form has been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Get the current step from the form data
    $step = isset($_POST['step']) ? intval($_POST['step']) : 1;

    // Store the form data based on the current step
    switch ($step) {
        case 1:
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            break;
        case 2:
            $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
            $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
            break;
        case 3:
            $_SESSION['university'] = $_POST['university'];
            $_SESSION['degree'] = $_POST['degree'];
            break;
        case 4:
            // Check if the user is logged in
            if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] !== true) {
                // User is not logged in, redirect to the login page
                header('Location: login.php');
                exit();
            }
            // Proceed with form submission
            break;

        default:
            // Invalid step, redirect back to the first step
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            exit();
    }

    // Increment the step for the next form
    $nextStep = $step + 1;

    // Check if there is a next step or redirect to the confirmation page
    if ($nextStep <= 3) {
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '#step' . $nextStep);
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '#confirm');
    }
    exit();
}


// If the form is not submitted, you can retrieve the stored values from the session
echo $name = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['name']) : '';
echo $email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email']) : '';
echo $address = isset($_SESSION['address']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['address']) : '';
$phone = isset($_SESSION['phone']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['phone']) : '';
$university = isset($_SESSION['university']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['university']) : '';
$degree = isset($_SESSION['degree']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['degree']) : '';

// Clear the stored values after displaying them in the confirmation step
if (isset($_POST['step']) && intval($_POST['step']) === 4) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
?>

<!-- HTML code for your_page.php with embedded PHP -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Form Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Next and previous buttons
                $(".next").click(function (e) {

                    var currentTab = $(this).closest(".tab-pane"); // Get the current tab
                    var nextTab = currentTab.next(".tab-pane"); // Get the next tab

                    currentTab.removeClass("show active"); // Hide the current tab
                    nextTab.addClass("show active"); // Show the next tab

                    $("a[href='#" + nextTab.attr("id") + "']").tab("show"); // Activate the next tab in the navigation
                });

                $(".prev").click(function (e) {

                    var currentTab = $(this).closest(".tab-pane"); // Get the current tab
                    var prevTab = currentTab.prev(".tab-pane"); // Get the previous tab

                    currentTab.removeClass("show active"); // Hide the current tab
                    prevTab.addClass("show active"); // Show the previous tab

                    $("a[href='#" + prevTab.attr("id") + "']").tab("show"); // Activate the previous tab in the navigation
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .btn-group {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Dynamic</h2>
            <!-- Add your other HTML code here -->

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                    <!-- Personal Information form -->
                    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
                    <form id="registrationForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>#step2">
                        <!-- Personal Information form fields -->
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required value="<?php echo $email; ?>">

                        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1"> <!-- Step indicator -->

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <!-- Contact Details form -->
                    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
                    <form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>#step3">
                        <!-- Contact Details form fields -->
                        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">

                        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"> <!-- Step indicator -->

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary prev">Previous</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="education" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <!-- Education form -->
                    <h3>Education</h3>
                    <form id="educationForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>#confirm">
                        <!-- Education form fields -->
                        <input type="text" name="university" placeholder="University" required value="<?php echo $university; ?>">
                        <input type="text" name="degree" placeholder="Degree" required value="<?php echo $degree; ?>">

                        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3"> <!-- Step indicator -->

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prev">Previous</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="confirm" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <!-- Confirmation page -->
                    <h3>Confirmation</h3>
                    <p>Please review your details before submitting:</p>
                    <p>Name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?></p>
                    <p>Email: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?></p>
                    <p>Address: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($address); ?></p>
                    <p>Phone: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($phone); ?></p>
                    <p>University: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($university); ?></p>
                    <p>Degree: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($degree); ?></p>


                    <form id="confirmationForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4"> <!-- Step indicator -->

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prev">Previous</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have the Javascript enabled, it won't post all the data to the server, so it won't be stored in the PHP session. And therefore it won't be echoed to the confirmation page. If you want to submit the data to PHP after each step, you'll need to add some AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code to use php best practices as I see it (my opinion).
This to me seems like a multi page form written in php with the help of jquery.
When the next button is clicked I submit the form using $_POST variables, then store the data in sessions and redirect using $_GET varialbles. This allows the person to refresh the page and use the back button without the page dying like it would on a $_POST only.
For the previous buttons I use jquery to redirect using the $_GET variable.

```
<?php
// Start or resume the session
session_start();

// best to define the page for security purposes
$page = 'registry_page.php';

$step = 0; // initialize step for security purposes
// Get the current step from the form data
if (isset($_GET['step'])) {
    $step = (int)$_GET['step'];
} elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $step = (int)$_POST['step'];
}

// Check if the form has been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Store the form data based on the current step
    switch ($step) {
        case 1:
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            header('Location: '.$page.'?step=1'); // redirect
            exit();
        case 2:
            $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
            $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
            header('Location: '.$page.'?step=2'); // redirect
            exit();
        case 3:
            $_SESSION['university'] = $_POST['university'];
            $_SESSION['degree'] = $_POST['degree'];
            header('Location: '.$page.'?step=3'); // redirect
            exit();
        case 4:
            // Check if the user is logged in
            if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] !== true) {
                // User is not logged in, redirect to the login page
                header('Location: login.php'); // redirect
                exit();
            }
            // Proceed with form submission
            header('Location: update_profile.php');
            exit();
    }
}
// If the form is not submitted, you can retrieve the stored values from the session
$name = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['name']) : '';
$email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email']) : '';
$address = isset($_SESSION['address']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['address']) : '';
$phone = isset($_SESSION['phone']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['phone']) : '';
$university = isset($_SESSION['university']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['university']) : '';
$degree = isset($_SESSION['degree']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['degree']) : '';

// Clear the stored values after displaying them in the confirmation step
// In my opinion this block of code is not applicable here,
// I think it should be on the login page or update page after you store the data
if (isset($_POST['step']) && intval($_POST['step']) === 4) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
//
?>
<!-- HTML code for your_page.php with embedded PHP -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Form Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#previous_from_review_section").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.location.href = '<?php echo $page; ?>?step=2';
            });
            $("#previous_from_3").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.location.href = '<?php echo $page; ?>?step=1';
            });
            $("#previous_from_2").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.location.href = '<?php echo $page; ?>?step=0';
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .btn-group {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h2>Dynamic</h2>
    <!-- Add your other HTML code here -->

    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php if ($step == 0) { ?>
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade show active">
            <!-- Personal Information form -->
            <h3>Personal Information</h3>
            <form id="registrationForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $page; ?>">
                <!-- Personal Information form fields -->
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1"> <!-- Step indicator -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php }  elseif ($step == 1) { ?>
        <div id="contact" >
            <!-- Contact Details form -->
            <h3>Contact Details</h3>
            <form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $page; ?>">
                <!-- Contact Details form fields -->
                <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
                <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"> <!-- Step indicator -->
                <button type="button"  id="previous_from_2" class="btn btn-primary prev">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php } elseif ($step == 2) { ?>
        <div id="education">
            <!-- Education form -->
            <h3>Education</h3>
            <form id="educationForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $page; ?>">
                <!-- Education form fields -->
                <input type="text" name="university" placeholder="University" required value="<?php echo $university; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="degree" placeholder="Degree" required value="<?php echo $degree; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3"> <!-- Step indicator -->
                <button type="button"  id="previous_from_3" class="btn btn-primary previous_from_submit">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php } elseif ($step == 3) { ?>
        <div id="confirm" >
            <!-- Confirmation page -->
            <h3>Confirmation</h3>
            <script>
                $('.next').click(function() {
                    $('#name').val()
                });
            </script>
            <p>Please review your details before submitting:</p>
            <p>Name: <span id="name"></span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?></p>
            <p>Email: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?></p>
            <p>Address: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($address); ?></p>
            <p>Phone: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($phone); ?></p>
            <p>University: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($university); ?></p>
            <p>Degree: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($degree); ?></p>
            <form id="confirmationForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $page; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4"> <!-- Step indicator -->
                <button type="button" id="previous_from_review_section"  class="btn btn-primary prev">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```